# wordpress buddypress custom registration form

Tags: php, css, wordpress, bootstrap-modal, buddypress

Would like to modify the form's CSS with bootstrap.

....\wp-content\plugins\buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members

have added the form-control and form-group section. just left the Profile Detail Section.

Part of The Code

```
<div class="register-section form-group" id="profile-details-section">

                <h4><?php _e( 'Profile Details', 'buddypress' ); ?></h4>

                <?php /* Use the profile field loop to render input fields for the 'base' profile field group */ ?>
                <?php if ( bp_is_active( 'xprofile' ) ) : if ( bp_has_profile( array( 'profile_group_id' => 1, 'fetch_field_data' => false ) ) ) : while ( bp_profile_groups() ) : bp_the_profile_group(); ?>

                <?php while ( bp_profile_fields() ) : bp_the_profile_field(); ?>

                    <div class="form-group" <?php bp_field_css_class( 'editfield' ); ?>>

                        <?php
                        $field_type = bp_xprofile_create_field_type( bp_get_the_profile_field_type() );
                        $field_type->edit_field_html();

                        /**
                         * Fires before the display of the visibility options for xprofile fields.
                         *
                         * @since 1.7.0
                         */
```